# How do I combine these two queries together? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

new here and to MySQL. Wondering how I can combine these two queries together to get 1 output.
**I want to include all hours less or equal to 30, AND hours that equal exactly 40.** I can get 2 outputs, but I am unsure how it would look if everything was put together.

The 2 commands are :

```
SELECT empID, hoursWorked FROM timesheet WHERE hoursWorked = 40;

SELECT empID, hoursWorked FROM timesheet WHERE hoursWorked <= 30;
```

[image: Image of the CLI]

Running MySQL v5.7.26 on Wampserver

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` in the condition:

```
SELECT empID, hoursWorked 
FROM timesheet 
WHERE hoursWorked = 40
   OR hourseWorked <= 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Union/Union all both the queries

```
    SELECT empID, hoursWorked FROM 
   timesheet WHERE hoursWorked = 40;
   Union 
   SELECT empID, hoursWorked FROM 
   timesheet WHERE hoursWorked <= 30;
```

Or simplest way

```
   SELECT empID, hoursWorked FROM 
   timesheet WHERE hoursWorked = 40
   Or hoursWorked <= 30
```